# Outlook won't display a single (specific) email, says there is a connection issue

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

This is a very odd behavior from my organization's Outlook web application.

The story: I get an email from a student with a couple of attached assignments a couple of days back. I look for it today -- and it's gone. I do a search and it doesn't show up at all in my Mac mail clien. When I go to the web and use Outlook (office365) it can "see" it -- but ONLY if I use the subject line as my search term -- putting in the sender's email gets no result. Further, when it displays (it shows there is an attachment, a PDF) it shows the error message that looks like this:
[image]

And won't download the files attached or the message. I checked the Outlook app on my phone, and similarly, it can show me there is a message there but it can't open it or download the files.

It only seems to apply to this single message. Which, by the way, was present on my computer's mail client a day or two ago, and accessible.

This is so weird. I tried clearing the cache and that didn't seem to have an effect. I can send emails to the account (I tested this, it seems to work) and I tried it with a file attached as well (that worked too).

Anyone have any idea what is going on? (I would put a more specific tag on this but I honestly don't know what would even apply in this situation).